# Use event.target.name instead of hardcoded value when setting state in nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested array i add dynamically to my state and therefore i dont know the key/name of the nested array and I can not give the key/name of the nested array when i need to add, update, iterate or remove somethings in the array. An example is the function addClick

```html
  const addClick = (event) => {
    // setValue({ event.target.name: [...value.(event.target.name)), ""] });
    setValue({ DevOps: [...value.DevOps, ""] });
  };
```

The comment contains the way i am thinking it should be. So instead of writing "DevOps" which is the key/name of the array, i want it to use the value of "event.target.name", but it will not use it. So how do i use the value when setting state of "value"??

other examples:

```html
  const removeClick = (event) => {
    //let vals = [...value.(event.target.name))];
    let vals = [...value.DevOps];
    let index = Number(event.target.id);
    vals.splice(index, 1);
    // setValue({ event.target.name: vals });
    setValue({ DevOps: vals });
  };
```

```html
{/*value.(input[form].name).map((el, i) => ( */ }
    {value.DevOps.map((el, i) => (
           <div key={i}>
           <Array
             name={input[form].name}
             placeholder={input[form].placeholder}
             required={input[form].required}
             key={input[form].placeholder}
             el={el}
             i={i}
             handleChange={(event) => handleChange(event, input[form].input_type)}
             removeClick={removeClick.bind(i)}
              />
             </div>
             ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  Using a variable/expression/etc. as a property name in an object literal requires bracket notation:

```
setValue({ [event.target.name]: [...value[event.target.name], ""] });
```

or:

```
setValue({ [event.target.name]: vals });
```

Comment: I changed the AddClick to: setValue({ [event.target.name]: [...value[event.target.name], ""] }); --- but it gives me this error: (value[event.target.name] is not iterable)

Comment: @NadiaHansen: Then what is `value`?  What is the state of the data before this operation, and what is the intended state of the data after this operation?

Comment: Before when it was: setValue({ DevOps: [...value.DevOps, ""] }); the  before state was value = {title: "titletext", DevOps: [""]}, the intended is value = {title: "titletext", DevOps: ["",""]} after one click

Comment: it worked before with the "value.Devops" but it is not optimal because of the name af the array can change

Comment: @NadiaHansen: Maybe `event.target.name` isn't what you expect?  Because if `[...value.DevOps, ""]` "works", and if `event.target.name` is `"DevOps"`, then `[...value[event.target.name], ""]` [is functionally equivalent](https://jsfiddle.net/Lod27j9k/).